# Collect AD Users from CSV input

Tags: powershell, csv, active-directory

I have a CSV file with over 1,000 names in "last,first" arrangement (with a header line).

I am trying to use this CSV as an input to query the AD Username of each person and output each result to a txt file. However, when I run the script as-is, I get an empty output file.

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$source = Import-Csv -path .\Input.csv
foreach ($line in $source) {
    $first = $line.first
    $last =  $line.last
    Get-ADUser -filter {(name -eq $first) -and (surname -eq $last)} -Properties SamAccountName > output.txt
    }
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `(givenName -eq $first)` instead of `(name -eq $first)`